# Predict user requests and prepare response

Tags: python, django, http, query-optimization, response

Is it possible to predict user request and prepare response even before a request is been made?

Test case: I have an endpoint that connect to another API that takes so long to respond up to 12 sec and that makes my application performance drop significantly while i can't modify that api and i can't stop using it.

- this api takes 2 user input which are start_date and end_date.

i want to find a way to optimise that and i was thinking of pre-preparing the data before even receiving a request for it but i still don't know if it is possible or not.

Technology i use VueJs in frontend and python(Django) in the backend. i would appreciate the help considering that matter.

i did try to make it into jobs but still the same the processes fire when the user ask for the data and the job take the same time as normal implementation in code

Comment: if you can indeed predict the request, launch it ahead of time and store the response, so when the user indeed makes this request you can immediately hand the answer. Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Caching is the go-to solution here. You can check Redis, elastic search, or similar solutions. Here without the code, we can't help you with exact solution.